# Java Sun PKCS#11 provider, HSM token LOGIN REQUIRED flag not set and empty list of aliases

Tags: java, pkcs#11, aliases, hsm

I'm Pavel and I'm mainly a Java developer. Here is my problem:

I'm trying to list aliases in HSM slot using Java Sun PKCS#11 provider and I'm getting an empty list. I have tried it with Java 6 and 7 on Windows XP/Server platforms.
I downloaded Sun PKCS#11 sources and examined them, switched on debugging, did other tricks so finally I discovered that the aliases map is empty because the token has LOGIN_REQUIRED flag not set. In Sun PKCS#11 implementation there is one IF construct so when this flag is not set even the PIN bytes are provided to the keystore there is no C_Login call!
I find it is strange! Can someone explain me if it is a bug in Sun implementation of PKCS#11 provider or there is a general idea behind it?
Anyway when I "hack" the original sources so if there is a PIN provided It makes a login op to token no matter if the LOGIN_REQUIRED flag is set or not and I got the aliases from the token!

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the Sun PKCS#11 provider tries to look for all the private keys that are visible publicly (without logging in) when finding aliases. After that, it will try and find a viable certificate chain for the private keys (first by PKCS#11 ID, then by X509 issuer).

I haven't got a clue why, but it seems to me that the PKCS#11 provider came to live at the same time that the Sparc T1 processor (Niagara) was introduced, which contains a cryptographic processor. There has never been any compatability data provided by Sun/Oracle - I presume their main focus was getting the T1 working within Java - this is however a guess. The only way to know for sure it to ask.

If you want to have a better provider, you can take a look at the IAIK software (whose lower level, open source, implementation is used by Sun/Oracle). They do provide support and compatability statements. This is, however, a commercial product.

Or you can get your patch accepted, I would certainly be interested in an *option* to login before the available private keys are looked up using PKCS#11 FindObjects. If you file a bug report I will certainly vote for it.